# FlatfileItemWriter encoding format issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Out batch job creates a txt file using FlatfileItemWriter with a special character. When the downstream system reads the specific special character, they read it in different format.

Actual text: FITNESS/WORKOUT – SLOT
when downstream system reads, they read as FITNESS/WORKOUT â€“ SLOT

I am not setting any default encoder for DelegateItemWriter.
Does it mean, I have to set encoding format as UTF-8 for my delegate method?
Or should I ask the downstream system to read using UTF-8 format.

TIA

Comment: Better both write and read happens in UTF-8 or a compatible charset depending on kind of text. By the way, can you find out what is the default charset in both systems?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `FlatFileItemWriter` uses `UTF-8`, but you can set a different encoding using `FlatFileItemWriter#setEncoding`.

Make sure both systems use the same encoding and your issue should be solved.